# Key binding for movement does not extend region when holding shift

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, motionevent

I'm using GNU Emacs on a MacBook Pro (macOS Sierra), and in init.el I have the Cmd-ijkl keys bound to emacs movement commands:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-j") 'backward-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-l") 'forward-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-i") 'previous-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-k") 'next-line)
```

When I use these bindings while holding the shift key they expand and contract the region as you would want. I recently decided to bind Cmd-h and Cmd-; to move-beginning-of-line and move-end-of-line, respectively.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-h") 'move-beginning-of-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-;") 'move-end-of-line)
```

I also unset the existing binding of Cmd-: so it wouldn't conflict with the use of Shift-Cmd-; to select to end of line.

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "s-:"))
```

Unfortunately, that hasn't proven to be enough. While Shift-Cmd-h does select to beginning of line, Shift-Cmd-; gives the error `s-: is undefined`. What can I do to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I also don't know why your way isn't working properly. Here's a temporary workaround. Hope someone comes up with a more decent solution.

Besides what you've already added, you may want to provide extra key bindings for "s-:".

```
(defun my-mark-end-of-line ()
  (interactive)
  (set-mark-command)
  (move-end-of-line))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-:") 'my-mark-end-of-line)
```

Additionally you may mark until the end of sentence too, with the built-in command:

`(global-set-key (kbd "s-:") 'mark-end-of-sentence)`

**EDIT:**

One interesting thing is that, when you check out the `C-h` help for key binding `C-N`, it is translated to `C-n`. The same thing goes on for `s-N`: it's translated to `s-n`. While, if you do `C-h k s-:`, it's not translated to `s-;`.

Comment: Refer to `C-h v this-command-keys-shift-translated`: "Shift translation occurs when there is no binding for the key sequence as entered, but a binding was found by changing an upper-case letter to lower-case, or a shifted function key to an unshifted one."